# ResultSet doesn't return values for DB2, but it return values if I try to do it manualy

Tags: jdbc, db2, resultset

I'm trying to get values from resulset, but it return nothing.
When i'm trying to do it through plain sql it return some values.

```
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM idoc.columns_to_show where user = ? "
                + DAO.DB2_UR_POSTFIX;

        Connection connection = Properties.getDocsConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement pr = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            try {
                pr.setString(1, user.getDomainName());
                ResultSet rs = pr.executeQuery();
                try {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        res.add(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
                    }
                } finally {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } finally {
                pr.close();
            }
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return res;
```

Comment: what is `DAO.DB2_UR_POSTFIX`?

Comment: @sma that is just with ur;

Comment: you mean `DAO.DB2_UR_POSTFIX = "with ur";` ? Can you please also e.printStackTrace() and check if you run into error?

Comment: @Jan no, there isn't any error. I found solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use column name "user" it is reserved name for DB2 database.
Therefore I couldn't find any result.

Comment: there's still **escaping** as another way to solve your query